# How can more than one builds share a workspace

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have 4 builds that are executed on the same build server. They use the same source code, but use different parameters. It is downloading 8 GB from the source control every time for each build. Can the 4 builds use the same workspace?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the code download location to one place by changing the following setting in all the 4 TFS Build Definition which is sharig the same source code:

```
'Workspace' tab > 'Build Agent Folder'
```

Here the value by default will be $(SourceDir) and

```
$(SourceDir) - Expands to $(BuildDir)\Sources by default
$(BuildDir) - Expands to BuildAgent.BuildDirectory
```

So by default, it will change according the BuildAgent and the corresponding build you are trying.

But, if you set the value of `Build Agent Folder` to a local path (available in Build Agent machine) like "C:\Builds\CurrentProject" or a UNC path like "\10.10.41.42\Builds\CurrentProject" then all these 4 builds will download to the same location.

After this once you queue a new build, in the `Parameters` tab in the following section:
`1. Basic > Clean Workspace` select `None` or `Outputs` if you don't want to download source code again OR select `All` if you want to download source code.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using the same workspace. Many TFS operations are performed per workspace (for example, the clean operations).

Each build definition will have a full copy of the source code, but there are things you can do to avoid having to download 8GB every build:

- Setup your workspace mappings to download as little as is needed (i.e. map to `$/Team/Solution/Project` not mapped to `$/`).
- Cloak any folders that are not required to be downloaded - we have 0.5GB of stuff we don't need.
- Set the build definition's `Clean Workspace` parameter to `Outputs`. Then it will only download the changes between the last build and the next one.
- Finally, you could setup a TFS Proxy Server on your build server and have that cache all the source code.